# Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Classname(? ? ?)

Tags: angular

I get this error when I try to use create new instance of a Class with parameters, but when not using parameters it works fine. What can be the problem?

Here is the class

```
export class Recipe {
  public name: string;
  public  description: string;
  public  imageP: string;

  constructor(name1: string, description1: string, imagePath1: string) {
    this.name = name1;
    this.description = description1;
    this.imageP = imagePath1;
  }

}
```

Here is the component

```
import {Component, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from '../recipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'rb-recipes-list',
  templateUrl: './recipes-list.component.html',
  providers: [ Recipe ]
})
export class RecipesListComponent implements OnInit {

  theRecipe: Recipe = new Recipe( 'New', 'blah blah blah', 'ddkkkiskxmdks');

  recipe = this.theRecipe.name;

    constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

if instead I do this in recipe.ts and recipe-list.component.ts respectively:

```
export class Recipe {
  public name: string = 'hello world';
  public  description: string = 'hello world';
  public  imageP: string = 'hello world'; 

}


import {Component, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from '../recipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'rb-recipes-list',
  templateUrl: './recipes-list.component.html',
  providers: [ Recipe ]
})
export class RecipesListComponent implements OnInit {
  //recipes: Recipe[] = [];

  theRecipe: Recipe = new Recipe()

  recipe = this.theRecipe.name;

    constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

works perfectly.

Comment: Why do you pass `Recipe` class as provider if you don't use it?

Comment: You don't need to inject dependency in providers array

Comment: @yurzui I also added same comments in 8 sec difference :p

Comment: Am very new to angular, saw some solutions online, so tried it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem should be with **this** keyword

```
export class RecipesListComponent implements OnInit {

  theRecipe: Recipe = new Recipe( 'New', 'blah blah blah', 'ddkkkiskxmdks');

  // recipe = this.theRecipe.name;          //<<<===removed this line

  recipe = theRecipe.name;                  //<<===removed this keyword

}
```

**UPDATE**: I just tested this and works perfectly.

```
export class RecipesListComponent implements OnInit {

    theRecipe:Recipe;

    constructor(){
      this.theRecipe = new Recipe( 'New', 'blah blah blah', 'ddkkkiskxmdks');
      console.log(this.theRecipe.name);
    }
  ....
}
```

OR

```
export class RecipesListComponent implements OnInit {

        theRecipe:Recipe;
        theRecipe = new Recipe( 'New', 'blah blah blah', 'ddkkkiskxmdks');
        constructor(){
           console.log(this.theRecipe.name);
        }
      ....
 }
```

**NOTE**. remove `providers:[Recipe]`(no need of that). You just need to **import** it wherever you want to use it which you are already doing.

**Update1**: I have tested it with plunker too and its working,

**DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/Vxdeyjwdjol9TnVhCV19?p=preview** check browser's console.

Comment: I guess you pointed a correct issue but that's another. In OP case somehow typescript isn't allowing to create instance of object when it has parameterized constructor model

Comment: @PankajParkar You can check answer now.

Comment: Do try to create instance of an object right outside the constructor, like what OP is doing

Comment: @PankajParkar You can check demo provided in demo. I have already tested it with my VisualCode and its working.

Comment: Oh.. I misreaded something, I can't check plunkr on mobile, sorry about that +1

Comment: @micronyks thanks very much your update solved the problem. But I don't really understand, I think what I did initially is similar

Comment: Thanks...Glad, it helped you. enjoy angular2!